# Unique JQuery Events for a Class

Tags: jquery, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to create a class that can send a unique jQuery event.  Example:

```
function Bomb(id) {
    this.evnt = $.Event("BOOM!_" + id);
    this.detonate = function() {
        $(document).trigger(evnt);
    };
}
var firecracker = new Bomb();
var nuclearbomb = new Bomb();

$(document).bind(firecracker.evnt.type, function(){
    // It's the fourth of july!!!
});

$(document).bind(nuclearbomb.evnt.type, function(){
    // We're dead
});

firecracker.detonate();
nuclearbomb.detonate();
```

How can I create a unique event within the Bomb class without having to pass in an ID to create a unique event string for the class?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean under 'unique'? If you need a custom class for event, then you'll need to extend jQuery's one or to provide your own implementation of Event interface and everything around according to the spec ([Document Object Model Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20030331/events.html)). See some ideas here: [Dean Edwards Blog](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/).

One more thing, I should mention, is, that you are using the same event target for all events. In most cases events of same type and name dispatched on the same object mean the same case. So if you need to process events differently, you'll need to differ them by name (as you've done) or by target (`$(firecracker).bind('ondetonate', function () { ... })`).

Sorry, if this was not specific, but I've just wanted to provide a general idea, how this could be solved.